# expected type different than actual type - Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have this simple method is `Haskell`, which dispenses much explanation:

```
-- IgnoreAfter problem: ignoreAfter 3 [7,8,9,3,4,5] == [7,8,9].
ignoreAfter 0 xs = []
ignoreAfter n (x:xs) = if length((x:xs)) >= n then
                           x : ignoreAfter(n-1 xs)
                       else
                          []
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
pattern_matching.hs:19:32:
    Couldn't match expected type `[a0]' with actual type `[a0] -> [a0]'
    In the return type of a call of `ignoreAfter'
    Probable cause: `ignoreAfter' is applied to too few arguments
    In the second argument of `(:)', namely `ignoreAfter (n - 1 xs)'
    In the expression: x : ignoreAfter (n - 1 xs)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Although I know the logic is sound, I can't figure out what I'm missing here ... could someone please help me out?

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer (click the white checkmark) if the answer meets your needs. It lets others know the question has been answered correctly, it awards you 2 points for accepting an answer, and it awards 15 points to the person that provided the answer :-)

Comment: Can you think of a more efficient way to do this? `length` is O(n), so your current algorithm is quite slow!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `x : ignoreAfter(n-1 xs)` to `x : ignoreAfter (n-1) xs`. () are not part of the function application in Haskell. When you passed `(n-1 xs)` to `ignoreAfter`, it treated it as just one argument. That is why you were getting the `Probable cause: ignoreAfter is applied to too few arguments` message.